# Sed replace in large text

Tags: bash

Scenario: Trying to modify large portions of our httpd configuration file using sed.

What I've tried:

```
read -d '' _OLD <<"EOF"
<Directory "/var/www/html">

#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride None
EOF

read -d '' _NEW <<"EOF"
<Directory "/var/www/html">

#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride All
EOF

echo -n ${_OLD}
echo -n ${_NEW}
sed -i "s/$_OLD/$_NEW/g" /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

If you notice the only thing that changed is `AllowOverride All` I only want to modify the rule for `/var/www/html` and not for the other instances hence why I'm looking in that whole block.

I know there is probably a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish. Direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -r '\%<Directory "/var/www/html">%,\%</Directory>% s%(AllowOverride)\s+None%\1 All%i'
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, my (out-of-date) version of `sed` doesn’t allow multi-line ‘old’ patterns (regular expressions), and requires multi-line replacements to have backslashes before the newlines, as in

```
sed "s/lifetime/birth\
…\
death/"
```

…so that’s one or two problems.  Another is that you’re using `/` as your delimiter even though your pattern and replacement have slashes in them.

I suggest that you use regular expression addresses:

```
sed '/<Directory "\/var\/www\/html">/,/AllowOverride/s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/'
```

In <strike>other</strike> words, do the `s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/` substitution on any applicable line(s) *between a* `<Directory "/var/www/html">` *line
and the next* `AllowOverride` *line*. 
(Watch out for the quotes in the first regular expression.)

Comment: If AllowOverride doesn't appear in the /var/www/html rule, this expression may change a later rule.

Comment: @Stephen: Good point.  However, the OP seems to know exactly what is in the file now.

Comment: @Scott that doesn't appear to work either and correct me if I'm using this incorrectly `sed '/<Directory "\/var\/www\/html">/,/AllowOverride/s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` actually outputs the whole file, no change to the actual text of the file.

Comment: @Peter: Looks right.  Try `sed -n '/<Directory "\/var\/www\/html">/,/AllowOverride/p'` to see whether it’s even finding the range (i.e., whether you have those first two regexes right).  If that yields nothing, try `sed -n '/<Directory "\/var\/www\/html">/p'` and `sed -n '/AllowOverride/p'`.  If the first command (in this comment) _does_ show the `"/var/www/html"` block, try `sed 's/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/'` to see whether the problem is there.

Comment: @Peter: P.S. I agree with @Stephen that it’s probably safer to end the range (the regex after the comma) with `</Directory>`.  Of course that means using a delimiter other than `/` (as he showed) or using `/<\/Directory>/` (like what I did for `/<Directory "\/var\/www\/html">/`).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a regex?  Sed supports them natively.  [More details here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html).