# Multiline sed replacement

Tags: regex, sed

I'm struggling with a multiline search/replace using sed. The file is the default apache vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ...
 <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
 </Directory>
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

What I want is to replace the AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All. The sed command I have come up with is:

> `sed -r -i 's/(Directory \/var\/www\/>[^<]*AllowOverride) All/$1`
>   `None/gm' /etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

The regex works fine based on my tests but not with sed. Do you know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sed replace in large text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764609/sed-replace-in-large-text)

Comment: Neither `/g` nor `/m` do what you think. The latter is not supported in `sed` at all. (Maybe you know what `/g` does but use it anyway? It's harmless but useless here.)

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. I'm not familiar with sed and I thought it would handle the common regex flags. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following might work for you:

```
sed '\#<Directory /var/www/>#,\#</Directory># s|\(AllowOverride\) None|\1 All|' inputfile
```

This would perform the substitution `s|\(AllowOverride\) None|\1 All|` only within the block `<Directory /var/www/>` ... `</Directory>`.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with `awk`

```
awk '/Directory \/var\/www\// , /\/Directory/ {sub(/AllowOverride None/,"AllowOverride All")} 1'
```

Within bloc `<Directory /var/www/> ... </Directory>` change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`